# Product type is invalid while linking images via import

Tags: magento, csv, import, product

We've been importing the links for images for a long time. But now we have a slight problem which is that Magento shows the Product type is invalid error.

This is how we link the images:
[image: Product linking with image]

This is how we link the images with the products. This used to work, well, it still does but some products seem to show the "Product type is invalid" error.
We already tried to just simply put _type column and simple as value, but this didn't work.
 We searched around for the problem but everyone suggested to put the _type column in it.
We used the normal import option, not the import profiles option.
Do you have any other suggestion?
If you need any more information, feel free to ask!
Thanks in advance

Comment: try to export file and change it and upload it